# How to set a LINQ resultset as DataSource in a gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview, repository-pattern

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application. I would like to gradually move the application from Web Forms to MVC. The first step I am taking is to move all the queries from the code behind to a Repository layer.

In order to do so I create a separate project (**class library**) where I place a **LINQ Entity Framework** a **Repository class** and **Repository interface**. This project is then referenced by the ASP.NET Web Forms.

The methods exposed by the interface always return an `IQueryable<T>` object (besides those returning scalar values which are not interesting for this issue).

How I can send the resultset to a **GridView**? Suppose I implement in the Repository class:

```
IQueryable<T> GetAll();
```

How can tell to the GridView that my data source is `GetAll()`? Is this code correct or shall I specify somewhere that the DataSource is a **LinqDataSource**?

```
 IMyRepository dataRepository = new MyRepository();
 myGridView.DataSource = MyRepository.GetAll().ToList();
 myGridView.DataBind();
```

I cast the `IQueryable<T>` `ToList()` because I expect the DataSource to be `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the type of DataSource.

I am not sure, where are you specify type of generic object T before you bind your list?

Comment: Thanks, it is just a convention. For methods common to all my Repository entities I use T. For those specific for a entity I specify the class